# Unsupported VB Version for this Project (SSDT)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-bi

I create project on VB 2017 and SSSDT 15.6.0 and close the project but when I reopen the projects then I'm getting error for Unsupported project please any one help me where I'm wrong

Project in SSIS and SSRS

please see the image below[Unsupported error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1Eqr.png)

Comment: Anyone .........

Comment: Known problem, existing bug reports to watch are [one](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/176585/ssdt-project-load-fail.html), [two](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/184571/ssdt-project-wont-load.html).  Possibly relevant is [this solution](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/166536/ssdt-not-present-in-visual-studio-build-tools-2017.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unload your project by right-clicking on it. Then edit the proj file and make sure that each "*PropertyGroup*" section has:

```
<Platform>Win32</Platform>
```

Example:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'DebugLocal' ">
    <FullPath>DebugLocal</FullPath>
    <OutputPath>bin\DebugLocal</OutputPath>
    <ErrorLevel>2</ErrorLevel>
    <OverwriteDatasets>False</OverwriteDatasets>
    <OverwriteDataSources>False</OverwriteDataSources>
    <TargetServerVersion>SSRS2008</TargetServerVersion>
    <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    <TargetReportFolder>Report Project3</TargetReportFolder>
    <TargetDatasourceFolder>Data Sources</TargetDatasourceFolder>
  </PropertyGroup>
```